# trait HasInputCol in package shared cannot be accessed in package org.apache.spark.ml.param.shared

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm working on a custom transformer in Spark 2.2.0.

Spark transformers inherit from `org.apache.spark.ml.Transformer` and in the example below I want to implement the `HasInputCol` and `HasOutputCol` traits.

```
package optimizer.feature

import org.apache.spark.annotation.Since
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.{Param, ParamMap, ParamValidators}
import org.apache.spark.ml.Transformer
import org.apache.spark.ml.attribute.AttributeGroup
import org.apache.spark.ml.util.Identifiable
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset}
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.shared.{HasInputCol, HasOutputCol}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, struct, udf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructType}

class SplitString(override val uid: String)
  extends Transformer with HasInputCol with HasOutputCol {
  def this() = this(Identifiable.randomUID("HashEncoder"))

  /** @group setParam */
  @Since("1.4.0")
  def setInputCol(value: String): this.type = set(inputCol, value)

  /** @group setParam */
  @Since("1.4.0")
  def setOutputCol(value: String): this.type = set(outputCol, value)

  override def copy(extra: ParamMap): SplitString = defaultCopy(extra)

  override def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {
    val split = udf((s: String) => s.split(","))
    val outputSchema = transformSchema(dataset.schema)
    val metadata = outputSchema($(outputCol)).metadata

    dataset.withColumn($(outputCol), split(dataset($(inputCol))))
  }

  override def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = {
    require(
      schema($(inputCol)).dataType.isInstanceOf[StringType],
      s"Input column must be of type StringType but got ${schema($(inputCol)).dataType}")
    val inputFields = schema.fields
    require(
      !inputFields.exists(_.name == $(outputCol)),
      s"Output column ${$(outputCol)} already exists.")

    val attrGroup = new AttributeGroup($(outputCol))
    StructType(schema.fields :+ attrGroup.toStructField())
  }
}
```

When compiling, I receive a series of errors: 
`trait HasInputCol in package shared cannot be accessed in package org.apache.spark.ml.param.shared` 
and 
`trait HasOutputCol in package shared cannot be accessed in package org.apache.spark.ml.param.shared`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `spark 2.2.0`, all these sharedParams are `private`.

Still you can write your transformer, Modify your code as below-

```
class SplitString(override val uid: String)
  extends Transformer {
  /**
    * Param for input column name.
    * @group param
    */
  final val inputCol: Param[String] = new Param[String](this, "inputCol", "input column name")

  /** @group getParam */
  final def getInputCol: String = $(inputCol)

  /**
    * Param for output column name.
    * @group param
    */
  final val outputCol: Param[String] = new Param[String](this, "outputCol", "output column name")

  setDefault(outputCol, uid + "__output")

  /** @group getParam */
  final def getOutputCol: String = $(outputCol)

  /** @group setParam */
  def setOutputCol(value: String): this.type = set(outputCol, value)

  // rest is as it is
    //...
  //...
}
```

> Please note that you can use this transformer for `read/write` purpose. To support that, you need to implement read/write.